# Sublime-like multiple selection operations in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

What I have is, I did a mistake

I aligned my tabular data like this

```
<tr>
  <td> first row </td>
  <td> second row </td>
  <td> third row </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td> first row </td>
  <td> second row </td>
  <td> third row </td>
</tr>
```

now to fix the mistake I want to copy the content of the second `tr` next to the first and enclose it with `tr`s

e.g.

```
<tr>
  <td> first row </td>       <td> first row </td>
  <td> second row </td>      <td> second row </td>
  <td> third row </td>      <td> third row </td>
</tr>
```

then do this manually:

```
   <tr><td> first row </td>       <td> first row </td> </tr>
 <tr> <td> second row </td>      <td> second row </td></tr>
  <tr><td> third row </td>      <td> third row </td></tr>
```

is there a nicer way than doing it manually? I tried using `ALT` mode , but it would repeat everything, e.g. the whole copied block for each line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using IntelliJ's column selection mode. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Mac) and select *Edit: Column selection mode*. You can then select the second block of `<td>` elements, cut them, move the cursor spanning 3 lines  to the first block and paste it after the original `<td>` elements.

Here is a gif illustrating the process:

[image]

Comment: btw, how did you do the gif?

Comment: @Toskan I used this app, which I discovered while attempting to answer this question: https://screentogif.codeplex.com/ it's pretty neat :)

Answer (score 1):

If `Column Selection Mode` is turned off, you should turn it on. It's in the `Edit` menu, about half way down. You can also turn it on (or off) with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> on Windows - not sure what the macOS equivalent is.

Once you turn on that mode, you just use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to add a cursor to the row above or below.

It's not quite the same as what you get with Sublime Text, but hopefully that's good enough to do whatever you want.